# Can C++ memory leaks negatively affect CPU usage?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, cpu-usage

I have a C++ program that has a pretty terrible memory leak, about 4MB / second. I know where it's coming from and can fix it, but that's not my main problem. My program is taking up a very large amount of CPU usage and it isn't running as fast as I want it to. I have two different threads in the program. One by itself takes ~50% CPU, which is fine, and the other by itself takes ~15% CPU, which is fine. Together however CPU usage is 100% and the program cannot run as fast as it needs to.

Can a memory leak by itself cause a problem like this? I know the program will eventually crash due to the leaked memory, but does a memory leak immediately lead to a slower program? By immediately I mean the program is too slow at the very start, not just when the memory footprint is huge.

Thanks!

Comment: I've got this ship called The Titanic, and we've got a bit of a leak down below. It's taking on water pretty fast, but that's not my main problem: I really need the deck chairs arranged just right, but the whole ship is leaning to the starboard side which means they slide about and my crew can't perform as fast as I need them to."

Comment: His reasoning, what is this I don't even...

Comment: Rep for that comment because it made me laugh out loud.

Comment: nickf: I understand your point. The reason I was disregarding the leaks was to determine if the program was possibly fast enough. If so I was planning to fix the leaks. If not the leaks won't matter much since I have to change the design anyway.

Comment: The point was the uncontrolled memory growth can cause all kinds of weird side-effects, and so those MUST be fixed before being able to tell what other problems may or may not be present.  It's useless to profile something for CPU usage if you're having uncontrolled memory growth.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Regardless of whether or not your memory leak is causing the problem it needs to be fixed. Once you fix the memory leak see if you're still having the problem. You should be able to answer your own question at that point.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the most logical way to proceed. I will look into it. 4MB / s is a huge leak for something that needs to be very fast, and I'm probably doing some silly things with allocation somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Allocations in general can be slow and it sounds like you're doing a lot of them here.  After fixing your leak, you will want to consider a pooled memory implementation to avoid thrashing your heap so much, especially in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 3):

It should not be a problem while you still have available memory. However, memory allocation is a relatively slow process, so depending on how often you do it, it might account for your problems.

Don't forget that a profiler is your friend for all and every optimization needs. It knows much better than you what your main bottleneck is.

Oh, and fix your memory leak now, while it's still easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been trying to find a decent (free) profiler but I haven't had much luck. The program I'm writing has to do numerous calculations every 10ms in a very small amount of time, say 1-5ms, so I can't just use something that tells me the overall CPU usage, which is what most free profilers seem to do.

Comment: The larger your heap gets, the slower allocation gets.  It could very well be a significant performance problem (especially if your leak causes exotic fragmentation).

Comment: A leak probably does not cause fragmentation - that's after all the result of freeing memory between two allocations. I suspect the problem is (1) that the CRT needs to call the OS to extend the heap, instead of recycling process memory and (2) the OS might need to swap out pages (including leaked memory from your app) to satisfy those heap growth requests.

Answer (score 1):

Well, allocation is slow and does require at least some CPU effort to search for appropriate blocks to give.  Besides that I wouldn't think so.  It sounds like your program is in quite a mess so I wouldn't doubt that there's some larger issue at heart.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your page faults.  In Windows, use Task Manager, and in Unix/Linux try ps.  It's likely that the extra processor time is being used to allocate additional memory to your process, and once the free physical memory has been exhausted, the OS has to swap out unused pages to the disk.

Another approach would be to use a profiling tool to see where the bottlenecks are in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several angles here: 
1) You have memory leaks. This is bound to cause page faults in your cache so data has to be sourced from RAM/disk. More I/O, more problems. Are you using a memory manager? If not consider using one. Look into dlmalloc for a start.

---

2) CPU usage 100% may not be due to this problem. Obviously the way to go is to first fix this leak and then use a profiler [Quantify is best, but costs. VTune is not bad, although I don't like the interface. Else gprof is not bad and its free.] and see which parts of your code is taking up CPU cycles.

---

3) I see that you are using threads. Syncing threads up is non-trivial. See if you are unnecessarily waiting for mutexes or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Disposing of previously allocated memory fragments should be relatively faster than their allocation and (as long as memory leak means *"memory lost due to missing deallocation call") it shouldn't really affect your speed, only overall memory usage.*

Although if you allocate huge amounts of memory every second and don't do proper deallocations, this could be the problem. *I had the same issue when wrongly compiled `gtkmm` + `librsvg` leaked ~5 megabytes per second on screen redraw and that, of course, had some notable performance impact.*

Of course, this doesn't mean you shouldn't eliminate your memory leaks if you know that they exist. Memory leaks could cause something more serious than performance troubles.